# Horizontal lines on video capture

Tags: camera, power, video

[image]

There are random lines in my camera recording. I have this system running on a vehicle. I doubt the following three to be the reason. Help me identify the root cause.

- Vibration of the camera connector strip
- Power issues on the camera and raspi
- compression capabilities of raspi

This happens only at certain frames in the video. In certain frames it has only a few lines. In certain frames its bad like in this one. In most frames the video is good enough.

Camere HW : V1 OV5647 camera with 1 IR [image]

Board : Raspberrypi 4 B 4GB

Command used : raspivid -o video.h264 -t 10000

Comment: Which model of the Raspberry Pi are you using, along with which camera? How are they connected? How is this recording obtained (what software or libraries are used?)

Comment: Edited the question with the details. Thanks for improving my question @user96931

Comment: Is your sdcard class10? looks like the problem is about writing speed. [*More*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=253483)

Comment: Ya, the card is a Good standard class10 card. The card is in a remote machine hence not able to give the brand.

Comment: Normally this is due to a poor PSU. How are you producing your 5V? What is it's max current? Are you using a good quality USB cable? How 'clean' is your supply?

Comment: I use good quality cables. The power comes from the car's main line 12v converted to 5v using an automotive grade dc dc converter. I think there is noise in the power  line.